# Using one column from another table as a reference for my current table MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 tables.
First table (user) containing 3 columns:

```
| user_id | username | password |
---------------------------------
|  253    | John     | 12345678 |
|  180    | Katrina  | jellyfis |
```

Second table (quiz score) containing 3 columns:

```
| score   |   rank   | answered |
---------------------------------
|  6520   |   56     |   51     |
|  9846   |   2      |   102    |
```

In this particular scenario, **John** has a score of **6520** points while **Katrina** has a score of **9846**.
Given that the **user_id** is in one table whilst **score** is in another table, is there a specific way I can establish a connection between these 2 columns?

Say for example, I've created a simple profile display in PHP where details about the user (score, rank and answer) are being shown. I want to display the score of that user while both of those columns are in different tables.

Hope I make myself clear enough.
For those who want the reason I'm doing this; it's because I'm working on a project that involves using 2 different tables based on the user's profile and the user's score.

Comment: Add foreign key `user_id` to `quiz_score`.

Comment: Never store passwords in plain text. Use a hash function to hide it.

Comment: It's not in plain text. This was just an example to demonstrate the concept of my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `user_id` column to the second table.

You will have to add `FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES firstTableName(user_id)` in your `create table` statement.  Please refer [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) for more details.

Your second table will look like

```
| user_id | score   |   rank   | answered |
-------------------------------------------
|  253    |  6520   |   56     |   51     |
|  180    |  9846   |   2      |   102    |
```

You can then join the two tables on user id column to get the details.

Comment: Thanks for the guide! I was just wondering though, is there a limit in approaching this? Say for example, would 600 number of members affect the process?

Comment: No. You will need a way to connect two tables and this is the easiest one.